# ¿Se puede compilar un script de Python creado en Pycharm para Mac?

Tags: python, macos, compilar, pycharm

Antes que nada decir cuatro cosas:

1. No soy programador, solo un profesor universitario de música
2. He buscado esta respuesta por meses encontrando Pyinstaller, Py2app, cx_freeze y ninguno lo logra
3. He intentado dos opciones: usando el terminal propio de la Mac y el terminal que ofrece Pycharm (con este segundo logré crear algo que funcionara en mi Mac, pero no en otra que no tuviera Python instalado)
4. Lo he intentado con distintos scripts, algunos con librerías externas (pyllow, pygame, music21, xlrd, etc) otros que solo usan tkinter, y otros sin ningún tipo de import.

¿Hay alguna opción para compilar un script de Python? Mi "devoción" a Python se debe a music21, una librería increíble para teoría musical, pero no me sirve de nada si lo que hago no lo puedo compartir a mis estudiantes.

Con un simple código

```
print("hello world")
```

y usando el pyinstaller

```
pyinstaller hello.py
```

el resultado al correr el exec que genera es

```
Last login: Tue May  5 09:44:57 on ttys001
iMac-de-CILA07:~ cila07$ /Users/cila07/PycharmProjects/pdfIndex/dist/hello/hello ; exit;
[5736] Error loading Python lib '/Users/cila07/PycharmProjects/pdfIndex/dist/hello/Python': dlopen: dlopen(/Users/cila07/PycharmProjects/pdfIndex/dist/hello/Python, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/cila07/PycharmProjects/pdfIndex/dist/hello/Python: code signature invalid for '/Users/cila07/PycharmProjects/pdfIndex/dist/hello/Python'

logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
Deleting expired sessions...none found.

[Proceso completado]
```

Comment: Agrega tu código y el mensaje de error que estés obteniendo por favor

Comment: Échale una mirada a py2app.

Comment: py2app tampoco lo logra desde Pycharm.